# Script to tile windows uses only half of the screen

Tags: vbscript, windows-10

I have a little problem: under Windows 7, 8, and 8.1 I always used a little VBScript to open two folders and tile them vertically.

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
objShell.MinimizeAll
Wscript.Sleep 600
objShell.Explore("some folder 1")
objShell.Explore("some folder 2")
Wscript.Sleep 600
objShell.TileVertically
```

But in Windows 10 this script doesn't work properly.

It works, but when launched, the two windows results tiled vertically not full in the screen but only in the left side (as if I wanted to dispose four windows on the desktop).

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: Your code worked fine for me when I just tested it.

Comment: Hi Ansgar, but you tested the code under Windows 10?

Comment: Since you specifically said that you have the issue on Windows 10 it would have been a little silly to test it on any other OS, wouldn't it?

Comment: I asked a confirmation to you because I tested  the script in 3 computers with Windows 10 in order to exclude ad issue with the laptop I'm using, and the results is different for each pc.

Comment: I tested on a vanilla install of Windows 10 Pro (32-bit) in a VirtualBox VM.

Comment: Thank you very much for your test. This thing is very weird... my first pc dispose the windows as I explained in the first post; the second pc open a window tiled vertically to the left and a windows in the center of the screen, and the third pc open the two windows tiled vertically, but spaced of about 50px between them. I will try to uderstand this enigma...

Comment: I have the same issue but for windows 11 for some reason doesn't seem to have TileVertically and other Tile schemas in the registry (if you right click on taskbar tilling options no longer avail. - instead 'they' encourage you to hover mouse over top right of window (where you would maximize/minimize screen) and they then have popup with like 2-4 different options as to how you want to arrange the windows - which is exceptionally limited in relation to predecessor functionality of this feature..

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that windows tiles more windows than you want, besides explorer windows there are script prompts which are also tiled. You can resolve the problem for example by creating tile.ps1 script:

```
Invoke-Item "some folder 1"
Start-Sleep -s 6
Invoke-Item "some folder 2"
Start-Sleep -s 6
(New-Object -ComObject  Shell.Application).TileHorizontally()
Exit
```

and silently run it by start.vbs script:

```
Dim objShell,objFSO,objFile
Set objShell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objFSO=CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
scriptdir = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
strPath = scriptdir & "\tile.ps1"
If objFSO.FileExists(strPath) Then
    set objFile=objFSO.GetFile(strPath)
    strCMD="powershell -noprofile -executionpolicy bypass -command " & Chr(34) & "&{" &_
     objFile.ShortPath & "}" & Chr(34)
    objShell.Run strCMD,0
Else
    WScript.Echo "Failed to find " & strPath
    WScript.Quit
End If
```